# How to close a table tag in if else loop

Tags: if-statement, razor, html-table

I am new on razor and facing an issue. I tried some solution that I found but none of them is working.

Below given is the code snippet that I want to implement in a partial view. I am opening the `<table>` but want to close it conditionally in the if loop, as shown.

The method from which I am getting the result, it populates a list property in my model and then return the model in the partial view.

First I am checking if the Type is "H" then table tag should open and the whole row with type "H" will be identified as heading. If type next entry says "D" that means it data present in the "H" type. And if the type of next element in the Details is also "H" then close the table tag. So from first identified "H" till the next identified "H" the table should exist and for the next "H" type a new table should start.

```
@if (Model.Details.Count() > 0)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < Model.Details.Count; count++)
    {
        //for heading
        if (Model.Details[count].Type == "H") 
        {
          <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        @if (Model.Details[count].Column1 != null)
                        {
                            <th>
                                @Model.Details[count].Column1.ToString();
                            </th> 
                        }
                        @if (Model.Details[count].Column2 != null)
                        {
                            <th>
                                @Model.Details[count].Column2.ToString();
                            </th> 
                        }
                        @if (Model.Details[count].Column3 != null)
                        {
                            <th>
                                @Model.Details[count].Column3.ToString();
                            </th> 
                        }
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @if (count < Model.Details.Count)
                {
                    if (Model.Details[count + 1].Type == "H")
                    {
                        </table>
                    }
                }
        }
        //for data under each heading
        @if (Model.Details[count].Type == "D")
        {
            <tr>
                @if (Model.Details[count].Column1 != null)
                {
                    <td>
                         @Model.Details[count].Column1.ToString();
                    </td> 
                }
                @if (Model.Details[count].Column2 != null)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Model.Details[count].Column2.ToString();
                    </td> 
                }
                @if (Model.Details[count].Column3 != null)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Model.Details[count].Column3.ToString();
                    </td> 
                }
            </tr>
        }
    }
}
```

On the opening table tag the error says

> "The "table" element was not closed. All elements must be either
>   self-closing or have a matching end tag."

And at the closing of the tag the error says

> "Encountered end tag "table" with no matching start
>   tag. Are your start/end tags properly balanced?"

I want to close the `` tag under the if condition. How can I do that? Please help..

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you move the table tag to outside your razor code

```
<table>
@if (Model.Details.Count() > 0)
        {
           for (int count = 0; count < Model.Details.Count; count++)
           {
             if (Model.Details[count].Type == "H") 
                {
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                @if (Model.Details[count].Column1 != null)
                                {
                                    <th>
                                        @Model.Details[count].Column1.ToString();
                                    </th> 
                                }
                                @if (Model.RetriveImpactDetails[count].Column2 != null)
                                {
                                    <th>
                                        @Model.Details[count].Column2.ToString();
                                    </th> 
                                }
                                @if (Model.Details[count].Column3 != null)
                                {
                                    <th>
                                        @Model.Details[count].Column3.ToString();
                                    </th> 
                                }
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                }
           }
       }
 </table>
```

This will remove the need to check if it's the final iteration of your Model (no need to dynamically close the table). It does means that if the value of your Count is 0 the table tag is still written (and closed) which may or may not be ideal.

Comment: thanks Dave for your quick response.
I want to do some more manipulation with the data by putting the tag in if loop.
Is there a way i can do that?
Do you want to have a look on the whole code?

Comment: @mailmehere Your approach could leave you with a closed table tag and then your code opens the TR tag! How many rows of headings are you going to have?

Comment: There could be any number of rows depending upon the data that'll be passes to the method. There can be 2 or 3 or 4 heading rows with 4 to 5 or sometimes no data rows for headings.

Comment: @mailmehere You could try to hack your orignal code, and put the <table> in a condition, like: *if (true){<table>}* Obiously since this always evaluates to true it means the table is always shown but this may get around the problem (but it is a horrible solution (if it works))

Comment: Just so we're clear, I meant make this change to your original code and not my suggestion! Is that what you did?

Comment: ya i made changes in my code..
i wrote like this..
if(true){<table>} the same way u told..but it didn't worked..